# tcl insert string at certain line in file

Tags: insert, tcl

I want to insert one string at the certain line ,and I know the line number.

ex.

```
#Aa_version = Aa/45.21-a32_1
#Aa_version = Aa/47.21-a33_1
Aa_version = Aa/45.27-a57_2 ->I can get this line number n
```

and I want to insert one line `Aa/49.27-a54_1` at line n+1

and put `Aa_version = Aa/45.27-a57_2`  -> `#Aa_version = Aa/45.27-a57_2`

output is like

```
#Aa_version = Aa/45.21-a32_1
#Aa_version = Aa/47.21-a33_1
#Aa_version = Aa/45.27-a57_2
Aa_version = Aa/49.27-a54_1
```

and my code is

```
set Aa ""
set fp [open $file "r+"]
set lines [split [read $fp] \n]
set idx [lsearch -regexp $lines {^Aa_version} ]
regexp {Aa(.+)} [lindex $lines $idx] Aa_version
set old_version "#$Aa_version"
set newAa [gets stdin]
set new_version "Aa_version =$newAa " 
puts $old_version ->replace $Aa_version
puts $new_version
close $fp
```

How can I put them at the correct line
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier and cleaner to handle the input file a line at a time and look at each one in turn instead of reading it all in one single go and then finding, altering and inserting elements in a list:

```
set fp [open $file]
while {[gets $fp line] >= 0} {
    # If the line starts with Aa_version...
    if {[string match "Aa_version*" $line]} {
        # Comment it out
        puts "#$line"
        # And read the new version and write it out
        set newAa [gets stdin]
        puts "Aa_version = $newAa"
        # Copy the rest of the file to standard output and exit the loop
        chan copy $fp stdout
        break
    } else {
        puts $line
    }
}
close $fp
```

But if you want to keep the current list based approach, [`lreplace`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lreplace.html) is your friend:

```
set fp [open $file]
set lines [split [read $fp] \n]
close $fp
set idx [lsearch -glob $lines "Aa_version*"]
# If a match was found...
if {$idx >= 0} {
    # Read the new verson
    set newAa [gets stdin]
    # Replace the version element with two new elements:
    # Commented out previous version, and new version
    set lines [lreplace $lines $idx $idx \
                   "#[lindex $lines $idx]" "Aa_version = $newAa"]
}
puts [join $lines \n]
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for kindly help. I have solved the problem by your answer2.Thanks!!!!