# How do I redirect the output on multiple lines in the Tcl to a file?

Tags: tcl

How can I redirect the output of a 'variable' on multiple lines in the Tcl to a file. For instance:

Suppose I have the file with the following lines:

```
Linha
Linha
Linha
Linha
```

and so on...

For Replacement:

```
Line
Line
Line
Line
```

and so on.

The reason for the question is when redirecting the output to a new file, I only receive the last line of the output. Where are the previous lines ???

This is the procedure I'm using at the moment:

```
# Open File
set open [open /tmp/linhas.txt]

# Read File
set read [read $open]

# Break File Line at the End (Space)
set line [split $read "\n"]

# Close File
close $open

# Going through a loop to capture only the necessary replacement
for {set i 1} {$i < 5} {incr i} {
    set out [string map -nocase { {Linha} {Line} } [lindex $line $i]]
}

# Create New File
set fp [open /tmp/outputFile.txt w]

# Insert output on the New File
puts $fp $out

# Close File New
close $fp

# View File New
exec aterm -e vi /tmp/outputFile.txt
```

Comment: `out` is set to a single line, that's why.

Comment: @Shawn I get it, but how can I get the other lines? I tried to create a new variable with 'gets' but to no avail.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70034562/9952196 for a similar problem that should be easy to adapt to your need.

Comment: open the output file _before_ the loop. Then you can puts each transformed line to the file.

Comment: @glennjackman Okay, I get it. Opening before the 'for' loop and inserting the output by the 'puts $fp $out' within the 'for' loop that solves the problem in question. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the comment of [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) the question is solved, so that it was like this:

```
# Open File
set open [open /tmp/linhas.txt]

# Read File
set read [read $open]

# Break File Line at the End (Space)
set line [split $read "\n"]

# Close File
close $open

# Create New File
set fp [open /tmp/outputFile.txt w]

# Going through a loop to capture only the necessary replacement
for {set i 1} {$i < 5} {incr i} {

    set out [string map -nocase { {Linha} {Line} } [lindex $line $i]]

    # Insert output on the New File
    puts $fp $out

}

# Close File New
close $fp

# View File New
exec aterm -e vi /tmp/outputFile.txt
```